# Bootstrap 3 centering nav add 5 pixel at the bottom of the links

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, height, navigationbar

I've centered the `nav` menu in Bootstrap. I've notice that my CSS rule add 5 pixels at the bottom of the links. You can highlight it when the menu is not hidden by the toggle button (width > 768)
Could you help me?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M8Lxh/)

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
```

CSS

```
.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just add a `margin-bottom: -5px` to `.navbar .navbar-nav` ?

Comment: If I add the margin when I see the menu with the toggle button the last item in the list is 5px close to the bottom respect the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add `vertical-align: bottom;` to `.navbar .navbar-nav`

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M8Lxh/2/)**